# How can we configure/schedule a Windows Job in Octopus Deploy?

Tags: octopus-deploy

**Can we configure/schedule a Windows Job in Octopus Deploy?**

I want to schedule windows jobs in Octopus Deploy.  My main objective is to automate these jobs and reduce the amount of human intervention.

Is there any way to configure windows jobs in Octopus Deploy?
I've tried to search the Octopus library but I'm unable to implement some of the libraries I've found.

Comment: Can you show what you have searched , what are your efforts?

Comment: There's a community-contributed step: [Windows Scheduled Task - Create](https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-templates/17bc51d1-8b88-4aad-b188-24a0904d0bf2/actiontemplate-windows-scheduled-task-create)

Answer (score 3):

If you package this script inside your NuGet package and call it Deploy.ps1, it should run a custom deployment that will bootstrap the schtasks.exe.

### Deploy.ps1

```
# -------------------------------------------------
# Octopus Powershell For Installing Scheduled Tasks
# -------------------------------------------------
#
# Ver   Who                     When      What
# 1.0   Evolve Software Ltd     17-05-16  Initial Version

# Script Input Parameters
# $TaskName - The name of the task that we use to create / remove
# $TaskExecutableName - the scheduled task executeable name
# $TaskSchedule - MINUTE, HOURLY, DAILY, WEEKLY, MONTHLY, ONCE, ONSTART, ONLOGON, ONIDLE
# $TaskModifier - Specifies how frequently the task runs in its schedule type. This parameter is required for a MONTHLY schedule
# $TaskStartTime - StartTime Specifies the time of day that the task starts in HH:MM:SS 24-hour format. The default value is the current local
# $TaskDisable - Disable the task after it's installed

# Script Version
$CurrentScriptVersion = "1.0"

function Main() 
{
    Write-Host "================== Installing Scheduled Tasks - Version"$CurrentScriptVersion": START =================="

    # Log input variables passed in
    Log-Variables
    Write-Host

    # Tear down any existing stuff
    Delete-Scheduled-Task $TaskName

    # Create scheduled task
    $TaskPath = $OctopusOriginalPackageDirectoryPath + "\" + $TaskExecutableName
    Create-Scheduled-Task $TaskName $TaskPath $TaskSchedule $TaskModifier $TaskStartTime $TaskDisable

    Write-Host "================== Installing Scheduled Tasks - Version"$CurrentScriptVersion": END =================="
}

function Log-Variables
{
    Write-Host "TaskName" $TaskName
    Write-Host "TaskExecutableName" $TaskExecutableName
    Write-Host "TaskSchedule" $TaskSchedule
    Write-Host "TaskModifier" $TaskModifier
    Write-Host "TaskStartTime" $TaskStartTime
    Write-Host "TaskDisable" $TaskDisable
    Write-Host "Computername" (gc env:computername)
}

function Create-Scheduled-Task($taskName, $taskPath, $taskSchedule, $taskModifier, $taskStartTime, $taskDisable)
{   
    # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    Write-Host "Creating task" $taskName
    Write-Host "Task path" $taskPath
    Write-Host "Task schedule" $taskSchedule
    Write-Host "Task modifier" $taskModifier
    Write-Host "Task start time" $taskStartTime
    Write-Host "Task disable" $taskDisable

    if($taskModifier)
    {
        Write-Host "Cmd: schtasks.exe /Create /TN "$taskName" /SC "$taskSchedule" /MO "$taskModifier" /ST "$taskStartTime" /RL highest /TR "$taskPath" /RU SYSTEM"
        #schtasks.exe /Create /TN $taskName /SC MINUTE /MO 5 /ST 00:00 /RL highest /TR $taskPath /RU SYSTEM
        schtasks.exe /Create /TN $taskName /SC $taskSchedule /MO $taskModifier /ST $taskStartTime /RL highest /TR $taskPath /RU SYSTEM
    } 
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Cmd: schtasks.exe /Create /TN "$taskName" /SC "$taskSchedule" /ST "$taskStartTime" /RL highest /TR "$taskPath" /RU SYSTEM"
        #schtasks.exe /Create /TN $taskName /SC DAILY /ST 03:00:00 /RL highest /TR $taskPath /RU SYSTEM     
        schtasks.exe /Create /TN $taskName /SC $taskSchedule /ST $taskStartTime /RL highest /TR $taskPath /RU SYSTEM
    }

    if (IsTrue($taskDisable)) {
        Write-Host "Disabling task: schtasks.exe /Change /TN $taskName /DISABLE"
        schtasks.exe /Change /TN $taskName /DISABLE
        Write-Host "Task disabled"
    }
}

function Delete-Scheduled-Task($taskName)
{
    # Stop Scheduled Task
    Write-Host "Stopping task:" $taskName
    try
    {
        schtasks.exe /end /TN $taskName
    }
    catch [System.Exception]
    {
        Write-Output $_
        Write-Host "Unable to end task - may not exist"
    }

    # Wait for it to stop   
    while($true){
        $i++
        $status = schtasks /query | select-string -patt $taskName
        if(!$status)
        {
            Write-Host "Task not running"
            break       
        }
        if($status.ToString().Contains("Running")) {
            Write-Host "Task still running: "$status.ToString() -foreground red
        } else {
            Write-Host "Task has ended: "$status.ToString()
            break
        }
        if($i -ge 60) # If task takes longer than 1 minute to stop bomb out
        {
            throw "ERROR: Unable to end task, please end it manually then kick of the deployment again"
            return -1
        }
        Start-Sleep -s 1
    }

    # Remove Scheduled Task (force delete)
    Write-Host "Deleting task:" $taskName
    schtasks.exe /delete /TN $taskName /F
}

function IsTrue( $boolString )
{
    if($boolString) #not null or not empty string
    {
        if($boolString -is [bool])
        {
            return $boolString
        } 
        elseif($boolString -is [string])
        {
            if(($boolString -eq "true") -or ($boolString -eq "True") -or ($boolString -eq "1"))
            {
                return $true
            }
        } 
        elseif ($boolString -is [int])
        {
            if($boolString -eq 1)
            {
                return $true
            }
        }
    }
    return $false
}

Main
```

You can now setup some variables to configure your scheduled task such as these.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. Will try your suggestion. Thanks for sharing your idea. In the meanwhile I have used a step template which creates a scheduled task based on an external XML file. Will post the final answer once it brings me the exact results.

Comment: Will implement you're idea too and see if it works